# Azure Key Vault Environmental Variables

Tags: c#, azure, environment-variables, azure-keyvault

In Azure is there a way to point an environmental variable to the key vault value? so I would only point to environmental variables and azure would do the rest.

Thanks in advance, Andrew

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for [Key Vault references](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-key-vault-references).

> Key Vault references can be used as values for Application Settings, allowing you to keep secrets in Key Vault instead of the site config. Application Settings are securely encrypted at rest, but if you need secret management capabilities, they should go into Key Vault.

Of course: Application Settings are available as environment variables, so using a Key Vault reference in an Application Setting effectively enables you to use it as an Environment Variable

Comment: Thats great, quite a bit of confusing setup but It does work now, Many thanks for your help. The main thing was getting an identity for the app (a function in my case) and then allowing the key vault to accept request from it using the Access policies on the key vault

Comment: You can use the syntax here for referencing the Key Vault variable in the application settings - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-key-vault-references?tabs=azure-cli#reference-syntax